# how to call a variable from the "parent" bash file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ftp

I'm in this situation:
I have a bash file in which there are 3 variables

```
ora=$(date +"%H.%M")
curdate="ore_$ora"
slideshow=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
```

This bash file is executed by cron automatically every 5 minutes (at xx:00 and xx:05).
So for example if the script is run at 17:30 of 26-05-2015 I have respectively these outputs: 17.30 ; ore_17.30 ; 2015-05-26

But this bash file takes 2 minutes (due to some necessary sleeps commands) to be run, and after these 2 minutes it will be 17:32.

After some commands and after these 2 minutes, in this bash file there is a command that runs another bash file (called sld.sh); in this sld.sh there are some FTP instructions, and especially a

```
send "$curdate".jpg
```

(in this sld.sh there is again the $curdate variable and $ora variable) but now $curdate is "ore_17.32" and no more "ore_17.30": I necessarely would like the $curdate variable to be my initial-parent variable (17.30), so is there a way to "recover" the initial curdate echo in the sld.sh file?

Thanks in advance!
Giacomo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`export`](https://superuser.com/questions/153371/what-does-export-do-in-bash) any variables you want to see in subshells and subprocesses in general.

```
curdate="ore_$ora"
export curdate
```

You can also combine it in one line.

```
export curdate="ore_$ora"
```